# Migrating social accounts from Auth0 to Azure B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to migrate a fairly large user database from Auth0 to Azure B2C.

The local email accounts I simply plan to have users reset the password - so I only need to create the accounts.

However, I don't understand how I can do something similar for social accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need in this case is called SignInType "Federated" for the user identity object. Take a look at it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#identities-attribute).

The important point to understand is that if you're migrating from an existing system you already have such a unique identifier (issuerAssignedId) from social account provider like Facebook. It can be used in base 64 encoded form.

For example, following the link above and using Graph API you can migrate the federated user with a Facebook account.

```
"signInType": "federated",
"issuer": "facebook.com",
"issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
```

Comment: The Create User document for the Graph API confirms what you are saying. It even has an example for creating a user with a social account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities

I will test asap, although probably not before August, and update how it went.

Comment: Make sure to not create a new Application at the Social provider, as then the social provider will return different unique id’s.